# What does JavaVMInitArgs.version really mean?

Tags: java-native-interface

I am trying to load a jvm from C++ via JNI and I originally mindlessly set my JavaVMInitArgs.version to "JNI_VERSION_1_6" without really knowing what it means.

Later, I installed java 8, modified my makefile to link the new libjvm.so and include the new jni.h, and changed my version to "JNI_VERSION_1_8" and now my call to JNI_CreateJavaVM returns -3 (JNI_EVERSION).

I switched back to JNI_VERSION_1_6 and it loaded fine. I checked the version number from my JNIEnv object and saw that it still said 1.6. Just out of curiosity, I tried again with JNI_VERSION_1_4 and found that not only did it still load fine, but that the version still was 1.6.

So, it appears that my executable is still pointing to the java 1.6 version of libjvm.so for some reason and that is probably some issue with one of my makefiles. I'll debug that on my own.

The real question I have for the people of stackoverflow is "what on earth does JavaVMInitArgs.version really even mean?"

I'm going under the assumption that the JNI versions correspond with java versions (so JNI_VERSION_1_8 is somehow related to JRE8) but I'm not clear on exactly how that affects what gets loaded or how it gets used.

My thoughts are that perhaps the version you specify indicates the minimum version of java that you need in order to run your program, so if you specify JNI_VERSION_1_X then you can load any JVM compatible with Java Y as long as Y >= X?

Also, does the JNI version only dictate the version required for C++'s interaction with the Java code, or does it dictate what the version of the java code itself? In other words, lets say my Java code does some stuff that requires Java 7, but my C++ code is isolated from that and only calls Java 4 compatible stuff, then can I set my JNI version to 1_4 and link my program with a Java7 version of libjvm.so?

I realize that I kind of asked a lot of questions at once, but if anyone can give me a description of how this works, I would be most grateful. And of course if anyone has an idea of why I can't seem to load Java8, I'd love to hear your advice as well.

### Edit

I figured out what why I couldn't seem to properly link in the Java 8 version of libjni.so. I had correctly added the new library to my -L g++ argument in my makefile, but my environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which apparently g++ checks first) still pointed to the old libjni.so. I set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the correct library (I probably also could have just removed it) and now it works great.

I'm still interested to know what exactly the JNI_VERSION values mean though.

Answer (score 1):

`JNI_VERSION` specifies the version of `JNI` interface. It may happen that for given version, JNI API is slightly different comparing to other one.

Example:

```
#ifdef JNI_VERSION_1_1
  JDK1_1InitArgs vm_args;
  ...
  ...
#else 
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 
  ...
  ...
#endif /* JNI_VERSION_1_1 */
```

Source: [Java™ Native Interface: Programmer’s Guide and Specification, The](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/javatm-native-interface/0201325772/ch13.html)

You can get version number supported by the library (you are linking to) using: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#getversion

You can also look for the enhancements inside `JNI` interface for given JDK release:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/13all-relnotes-5461743.html